# jQuery datatables ajax callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-events

I am using jQuery DataTables and doing server-side data. I'm trying to call a function when the ajax call returns. I tried inserting this `fnCallback2` which calls my function and the original function, but jQuery just throws an error (and doesn't tell me what the error is) and skips out.

```
$("#brands").dataTable( {
"bServerSide" : true,
"sAjaxSource" : "ajax.php",
"fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    fnCallback2 = function(a,b,c){
        fnCallback.call(a,b,c);
        update_editable();
    };
    $.ajax( {
        "dataType" : 'json',
        "type" : "POST",
        "url" : sSource,
        "data" : aoData,
        "success" : fnCallback2
    });}});
```

I also tried adding the `fnInitComplete` parameter, but that only gets called the first time, not after subsequent pages.

```
"fnInitComplete": function(){
update_editable();
},
```

How do I correctly call my code after the ajax request so that the original callback gets called as well?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Another option is to use the [fnDrawCallback](http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks) that is called after each draw event. Which will be done after every ajax request.

```
"fnDrawCallback" : function() {
    update_editable();
}
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! However it was firing AJAX functions like jQueryUI dialogs each time, so thought to share here that if you are binding a function firstly need to unbind the event to work.. IE:           "fnDrawCallback": function() {
     $("#ask_container").find('a[href^="includes/view"].t3_txt').unbind("click");
    $("#ask_container").find('a[href^="includes/view"].t3_txt').on("click",function(b){b.preventDefault();
    var ce=$(this).attr("href");   ... the rest of your function goes here!

Comment: The key (which used to be `fnDrawCallback`) is now [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) (since: 1.10). Also, the function receives a `settings` object as first argument.

Comment: @basic6 Although the documentation says the `settings` object is NOT optional, passing nothing also works. Any idea why/how?

Comment: @Sterex: Passing nothing? *DataTables* is passing that settings object to your callback. Whether you use it or not is up to you.

Answer (score 12):

#### SOLUTION

With DataTables 1.10 there are multiple ways to handle Ajax completion event.

- Using [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option:

  ```js
  var table = $("#example").DataTable({
       serverSide: true,
       ajax: {
           url: "/test/0",
           dataSrc: function(d){

               // TODO: Insert your code

               return d.data;    
           }
       }
  });
  ```
- Using [`xhr`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event:

  ```js
  $("#example").on('xhr.dt', function(e, settings, json, xhr){
      // TODO: Insert your code
  });

  var table = $("#example").DataTable({
       serverSide: true,
       ajax: {
           url: "/test/0"
       }
  });
  ```

There is one extra advantage to using [`xhr`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr) event versus [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option:

> As of DataTables 1.10.7 this event is triggered by both success and error conditions when the Ajax request completed (i.e. it is always triggered regardless of the outcome of the Ajax request).

#### DEMO

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3zrqp16/6/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 8):

Try this way :

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
       /* Add some extra data to the sender */
       aoData.push( { "name": "more_data", "value": "my_value" } );
       $.ajax( {
         "dataType" : 'json',
         "type" : "POST",
         "url" : sSource,
         "data" : aoData,
         "success" : function(json) {
           /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, 
             then tell DataTables */
           fnCallback(json)
       } );
}
```

You can then do what ever you want to do before the `fnCallback(json);` line - including calling a function.

Comment: I looked at that, but it forces a GET, and I'm potentially passing a lot of data back to the server. I'd like to stick with POST.

Comment: @BobBaddeley Updated my answer - untested

Comment: After testing, it didn't work. It looks to be equivalent to what I posted in the original question. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
    $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
       fnCallback(json)
}).complete(function(){update_editable(););
}
```